# How to read .psv file data which contains (pipe-separated) values using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, readfile

How to read .psv file content using javascript which contains pipe separated values in it.

The file content is:

```
A|1|"A    india               "|1|"A    hyderabad                "
A|1|"A    india               "|2|"A    banglore                 "
A|1|"A    india               "|3|"A  chennai                    "
A|1|"A    india               "|4|"A   amaravathi                "
A|1|"A    india               "|5|"A   delhi                     "
A|1|"A    india               "|6|"A   uttarpradesh              "
A|1|"A    india               "|7|"A   west bengal               "
A|1|"A    india               "|8|"A    punjab                   "
A|1|"A    india               "|9|"A   mizoram                   "
A|1|"A    india               "|10|"A   rajasthan                "
A|1|"A    india               "|11|"A    kerala                  "
A|1|"A    india               "|12|"A   mumbai                   "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|1|"B    florida                  "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|2|"B    new york                 "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|3|"B    texas                    "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|4|"B    miami                    "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|5|"B    alanta                   "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|6|"B    chicago                  "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|7|"B    washington               "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|8|"B    boston                   "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|9|"B    los angels               "
```

This is code I tried with

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('sample-file.psv', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Expected Output:

```
[{ a : india },{ b : USA },{ india : hyderabad },{ india : banglore },{ india : chennai },{ india : kerala },{ USA : newyork },{ USA : boston },{ USA : florida }]
```

Does any one know how to do it?
Please help to solve this and Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried using below code var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('sample-file.psv', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
   console.log(data);
});

Comment: Are you sure that the file content is correct? I guess something is misplaced, could be double quotes.

Comment: Why do not you turn your data into CSV?

Comment: Yes file content is right i have check

Comment: Rafael Lopes ---- You mean try to convert psv into csv file ?

Comment: replacing the pipes ( | ) by commas ( , )

Comment: Please add the expected output as well. And do you want the output in console or file?

Comment: Need output in the console i will update expected output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the data spliting the content, on this way:

```js
data = `A|1|"A    india               "|1|"A    hyderabad                "
A|1|"A    india               "|2|"A    banglore                 "
A|1|"A    india               "|3|"A  chennai                    "
A|1|"A    india               "|4|"A   amaravathi                "
A|1|"A    india               "|5|"A   delhi                     "
A|1|"A    india               "|6|"A   uttarpradesh              "
A|1|"A    india               "|7|"A   west bengal               "
A|1|"A    india               "|8|"A    punjab                   "
A|1|"A    india               "|9|"A   mizoram                   "
A|1|"A    india               "|10|"A   rajasthan                "
A|1|"A    india               "|11|"A    kerala                  "
A|1|"A    india               "|12|"A   mumbai                   "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|1|"B    florida                  "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|2|"B    new york                 "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|3|"B    texas                    "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|4|"B    miami                    "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|5|"B    alanta                   "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|6|"B    chicago                  "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|7|"B    washington               "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|8|"B    boston                   "
B|1|"B    USA                 "|9|"B    los angels               "`

data.split('\n').map(function(line){ 
    console.log(line.split('|')) 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, How did to converted psv file content into string content.

Comment: I used the data directly in the file just to exemplify.
The data can come from the file as well, this part does not matter.

Comment: Thank you so much Rafael Lopes you saved my day. Once again thank a lot